# Return Error through JsonResult Without [] Appended

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to all this so please bear with me. I am calling a JsonResult method in my controller via AJAX. The JsonResult action method calls a private method that calls a stored procedure, loads up the data into an object, and returns it to be serialized and returned to the client AJAX call.

That all works great, but when I catch Oracle exceptions I want to be able to return the error. I am currently just doing a Response.Write in my catch but because it's going through a JsonResult action it will append [] to the message. I could always trim that on the client side but I get the feeling I shouldn't be doing it this way, or there is a better cleaner way.

AJAX Call:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Controller/JsonResultActionMethod",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { someVar: someData },
    cache: false,
    success: function (results) {
        // Do some stuff
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

JsonResult Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult JsonResultActionMethod(string someVar)
    {
        var myObjects = GetObjects(someVar);
        return Json(myObjects , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

GetObjects Method (Calls stored procedure and returns list of myObject)

```
    private List<myObject> GetObjects(string someVar)
    {
        var myObjList = new List<InspectionModel>();

        try
        {
            // call stored procedure, create new instance of object, and load up myObjList. All of this works just fine
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            // error handling is a bit more robust. simplified for example. ex.Message, when returned to page and displayed via xhr.responseText will appear as such: "Some error message from Oracle[]"
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        return disasterList;
    }
```

Is there a way to return error messages from the catch{} in such a way that it could be serialized into a JSON object? I thought about adding a List property to myObject and storing errors in there. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why catch at all and just return the 500 to the error handler in your javascript?  The problem is that your are still returning an empty list in your scenario.  which is going to get serialized to [].

Comment: I want to catch because the stored procedure actually returns the reason (no data or no more data for that queue) and it helps with the messaging for the end user. If I just returned the 500 I would have to parse that on the client side to get the ORA error message. 

Honestly wondering, should I do that? Is that the right way to get the message I want, by just parsing the 500?

Comment: remove the catch block, debug javascript, and check it out. the ORA message might be buried in an inner exception.  I don't know of the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a good question as it relates to API design in general. I haven't been able to find the "best" solution to this. But I would create a BaseResponse class that contained a field for an Exception and then the actual object itself. Like this:

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Exception Error { get; set; }

    public object GetResponse() {

        //If an exception has not been thrown then just return your data
        if(Error == null)
            return Data;

        //If an exception has been thrown, return the exception
        return Error;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this BaseResponse class from the Controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetObjects(string someVar)
{
    var response = BaseResponse<InspectionModel>();

    try {
        response.Data = GetObjects(someVar);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        response.Error = e;
    }

    return Json(response.GetResponse() , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

There are alot better ways to wrap all this using Filters. Then all this can happen in the background and you don't have to duplicate this code everywhere.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to respond and mark as the answer. I haven't yet implemented, but I like this solution a lot and will be doing so soon. Thanks!